# In hping3, What is "win=x"

Tags: network-scanners

In the verbose output of hping3, what is win=x. For example,

```
len=46 ip=4.2.2.1 ttl=56 DF id=32841 sport=52 flags=RA seq=2 win=0 rtt=285.4 ms
len=46 ip=4.2.2.1 ttl=56 DF id=32842 sport=52 flags=RA seq=2 win=29200 rtt=245.4 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the TCP Window Size, coming from struct `th_win` in hping3's `ars.h` header file:

```
/* The TCP header structure */
struct ars_tcphdr {
    __u16   th_sport;               /* source port */
    __u16   th_dport;               /* destination port */
...
    __u16   th_win;                 /* window */
...
};
```

The printout you quote appears to come from `waitpacket.c`:

```
    printf("sport=%d flags=%s seq=%d win=%d rtt=%.1f ms\n",
        ntohs(tcp.th_sport), flags, sequence,
        ntohs(tcp.th_win), ms_delay);
```

The TCP Window Size is also known as the TCP Receive Window Size.  To quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol), "[Window size is] the size of the receive window, which specifies the number of window size units that the sender of this segment is currently willing to receive."

Comment: That;s what I thought it was, but I wasn't sure. After a couple Google searches, I couldn't find any information about it. Thanks!

Comment: The man page explains it: https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/hping3/hping3.8.en.html